# Extending holomorphic function of two variables

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $X=\{(z_1,z_2):|z_1|<1,|z_2|<2\}\cup\{(z_1,z_2):|z_1|<2,|z_2|<1\}$ and $Y=\{(z_1,z_2):|z_1|,|z_2|<2, |z_1z_2|<2\}$. Then, $X\subset Y\subset \mathbb C^2$. How to show that any holomorphic function on $X$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $Y$?

This is a result used in the answer of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59479/partial-bar-partial-lemma-for-contractible-domains), in which the author constructed a $\bar\partial$-closed form on $X$ which is not $\bar\partial$-exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on $X$.
Let $a_{n,m}$ be the coefficients in the power series expansion of $f$ around $(0,0)$. From Cauchy's formula we get
$$a_{n,m}=-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{|z_1|=1-\varepsilon_1,|z_2|=2-\varepsilon_2}\frac{f(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)}{
\zeta_1^{n+1}\zeta_2^{m+1}}d\zeta_1d\zeta_2$$

Taking the modulus, $|a_{n,m}|\le \frac{1}{4\pi ^2}\frac{M(\varepsilon)}{(1-\varepsilon_1)^{n}(1-\varepsilon_2)^m}$. This implies that the power series converges absolutely in the region $\{|z_1|<1,|z_2|<2\}$. The same reasoning
applied to $\{|z_1|<2,|z_2|<1\}$ implies the absolute convergence of the power series in that region. Now since power series converges in a logarithmically convex Reinardt domain (this is a standard result in a course in scv), it suffices to prove that the smallest logarithmically convex Reinardt domain containing $X$ is $Y$.
This is easy to do and I encourage you to try proving it yourself.